# Setting divs in an html template with data from a database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Let's say I have an html template similar to this

```
<template id="template">
    <div class="fname"></div>
    <div class="lname"></div>
</template>
```

I use this jquery/JavaScript code to display multiple versions of this template with

```
var bodyDiv = document.getElementById('body');

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var tmpl = document.getElementById('template').content.cloneNode(true);
    bodyDiv.appendChild(tmpl);
}
```

However, obviously the templates which are copied/pasted are all the same and contain nothing in them except the empty divs. Is there a way to use ajax or something to get data from a database and load it into the divs in the for loop? I was thinking something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var tmpl = document.getElementById('template').content.cloneNode(true);
        // pseudo code
        tmpl.($'.fname') = (SELECT fname FROM users WHERE id = i);
        tmpl.($'.lname') = (SELECT lname FROM users WHERE id = i);
        bodyDiv.appendChild(tmpl);
}
```

I have very little experience with templates and no experience with AJAX or accessing databases from a JavaScript file.

The end result should be 5 templates on the screen each containing a first and last name from the table users on some database.

Comment: 1) Exposing SQL statements via the client will certainly mean your database will be hacked. 2) Look at backbone.js + underscore.js for DB communication and templating.

Comment: You will want to read this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a server-side script, you could pull the data using `$.ajax()`. [Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Then your code would resemble something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: yourServerSideScriptPage,
    dataType: json //optional, but json is easy to parse
}).done(function(data){
     $(".fname").append(data.fname);
     $(".lname").append(data.lname);
});
```

Then you add your sql statements in a function on the server side which keeps them better protected.

This is just a very quick and dirty example, but you should be able to adjust it to your specific needs.